# Trouble passing arguments to a page through a controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am having trouble with a line in a controller:

```
public function checked(Request $request)
{
    $user = DB::table('user2s')->where('name', $request->name)->first();
    if (isset($user))
    return redirect ('/’,['user'=>$request->name]);
    else
    return redirect('/');
}
```

The error is `"syntax error, unexpected 'user' (T_STRING)" line 29`.
The code before works because it recognizes when the passed name does not belong to a user in the users' table.

It works if written like: `return $user->id;` // or `$user->body`, the correct info is displayed.

It doesn't work with `redirect (compact('user'))` either.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function checked(Request $request)
{
    $user = DB::table('user2s')->where('name', $request->name)->first();
    if (isset($user))
    return redirect ('/',['user'=>$request->name]);
    else
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Your error was caused in the first redirect. You have used `’` instead of `'`.